# Creating submodules in a recently converted svn to git repo

Tags: svn, git, git-submodules

I have just recently converted an old company svn repo which has a bunch of projects into a git repo

ie.

repo

- project-1
- project-2
- project..n

From within this new git repo how would you recommend creating a submodule for each individual project?

Comment: Hey Piper, I saw you posting a lot of `git` questions tonight (which is completely fine!) but just wanted to make sure you were aware of http://gitready.com and the Git Community Book: http://book.git-scm.com/ which might help you with some of your questions. The community book even has some screencasts in it. Again, feel free to ask questions here... just wanted to pass that along to you.

Comment: it was 2 questions... and i am reading as much as I can.... the docco is not always clear... but the minute a question is answered, the docco suddenly becomes clearer...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a separate git repo for each sub module.

It works better for distributed source control to have one project per repository.  One reason is to minimize the amount of history and meta data you have to sync down when cloning the repo.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Git Submodule Tutorial](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitSubmoduleTutorial) on the git wiki.